# Docker build step not persisting filesystem changes

Tags: docker, webpack

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile for building a Rails app that includes webpacked frontend assets.

The step with `RUN bin/rails assets:precompile` calls webpack to build all the .js and .css assets to publish to `public/packs`. This works fine. The problem is, the changes from this `RUN` step are not persisted. One would expect the following to work:

```
RUN bin/rails assets:precompile && \
    test -d /opt/app/public/packs && \
    ls /opt/app/public/packs/* && \
    du -sh /opt/app/public/packs

RUN ls /opt/app/public/packs/*
```

The first command executes just fine and shows all the built assets. Great. The second command fails with:

```
ls: cannot access '/opt/app/public/packs/*': No such file or directory
```

I've built the image with `--no-cache` and get the same result. I also see this same result in our CI workflow.

The question is: **what can cause the results of a `RUN` step to not be saved?**

Here's an except of the build process showing that the asset builds are working fine and the result can be seen:

```
Step 34/35 : RUN bin/rails assets:precompile &&     test -d /opt/app/public/packs &&     ls /opt/app/public/packs/* &&     du -sh /opt/app/public/packs
 ---> Running in 5c31033bd34c                                                                                                                                                   yarn install v1.22.10                                                                                                                                                           [1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.                                                                                                                                                     Done in 0.39s.                                                                                                                                                                  Compiling...
Compiled all packs in /opt/app/public/packs                                                                                                                                     yarn run v1.22.10                                                                                                                                                               $ /opt/node_modules/.bin/webpack --config /opt/app/config/webpack/production.js
Hash: 3a1c2a59a582aeab432b                                                                                                                                                      Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 16798ms                                                                                                                                                                   Built at: 03/23/2021 11:04:01 AM
                                                                    Asset        Size   Chunks                                Chunk Names
                                             css/application-ad4e93e8.css     195 KiB  0, 1, 2  [emitted] [immutable]         application
                                          css/application-ad4e93e8.css.br    27.1 KiB           [emitted]
                                          css/application-ad4e93e8.css.gz    34.9 KiB           [emitted]
                                             css/stylesheets-ad4e93e8.css     195 KiB        2  [emitted] [immutable]         stylesheets
                                          css/stylesheets-ad4e93e8.css.br    27.1 KiB           [emitted]
                                          css/stylesheets-ad4e93e8.css.gz    34.9 KiB           [emitted]
                                   js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js     569 KiB  0, 1, 2  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  application
                       js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.LICENSE.txt     2.2 KiB           [emitted]
                                js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.br     122 KiB           [emitted]
                                js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.gz     148 KiB           [emitted]
                               js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map    1.86 MiB  0, 1, 2  [emitted] [dev]               application
                            js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map.br     402 KiB           [emitted]              [big]
                            js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map.gz     491 KiB           [emitted]              [big]
                                        js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js    1.31 KiB        1  [emitted] [immutable]         images
                                     js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.br   600 bytes           [emitted]
                                     js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.gz   673 bytes           [emitted]
                                    js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.map    5.13 KiB        1  [emitted] [dev]               images
                                 js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.map.br    1.72 KiB           [emitted]
                                 js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.map.gz    1.92 KiB           [emitted]
                                   js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js  1010 bytes        2  [emitted] [immutable]         stylesheets
                                js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.br   468 bytes           [emitted]
                                js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.gz   519 bytes           [emitted]
                               js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.map    4.55 KiB        2  [emitted] [dev]               stylesheets
                            js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.map.br    1.55 KiB           [emitted]
                            js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.map.gz    1.72 KiB           [emitted]
                                                            manifest.json    2.63 KiB           [emitted]
                                                         manifest.json.br   598 bytes           [emitted]
                                                         manifest.json.gz   681 bytes           [emitted]
                             media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-674f50d2.eot     162 KiB           [emitted]
                          media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-674f50d2.eot.br    88.3 KiB           [emitted]
                          media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-674f50d2.eot.gz    95.9 KiB           [emitted]
                             media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-912ec66d.svg     434 KiB           [emitted]              [big]
                          media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-912ec66d.svg.br     108 KiB           [emitted]
                          media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-912ec66d.svg.gz     131 KiB           [emitted]
                           media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-af7ae505.woff2    75.4 KiB           [emitted]
                             media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-b06871f2.ttf     162 KiB           [emitted]
                          media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-b06871f2.ttf.br    88.3 KiB           [emitted]
                          media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-b06871f2.ttf.gz    95.8 KiB           [emitted]
                            media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-fee66e71.woff    95.7 KiB           [emitted]
   media/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold-276b1b48304f694814bb94f404ce806c.otf     106 KiB           [emitted]
media/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold-276b1b48304f694814bb94f404ce806c.otf.br      50 KiB           [emitted]
media/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold-276b1b48304f694814bb94f404ce806c.otf.gz    59.5 KiB           [emitted]
   media/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold-c95e32a64b94c190a618a5f7a337b0b6.ttf     135 KiB           [emitted]
media/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold-c95e32a64b94c190a618a5f7a337b0b6.ttf.br    54.9 KiB           [emitted]
media/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold-c95e32a64b94c190a618a5f7a337b0b6.ttf.gz    64.6 KiB           [emitted]
     media/images/fonts/Noah-Regular-160999b118eefa6cf7dad830b2662250.otf    96.5 KiB           [emitted]
  media/images/fonts/Noah-Regular-160999b118eefa6cf7dad830b2662250.otf.br    46.4 KiB           [emitted]
  media/images/fonts/Noah-Regular-160999b118eefa6cf7dad830b2662250.otf.gz    54.4 KiB           [emitted]
      media/images/icon/contact-icon-4948acb3b4a035afc087d4a49006bdc1.png    1.13 KiB           [emitted]
       media/images/icon/credit-card-5e76418433bf1520bb14dbb2d059f2f6.png    1.04 KiB           [emitted]
                   media/images/logo-a53b7b1aecd172e93f6f7f75aae92186.svg    3.91 KiB           [emitted]
                media/images/logo-a53b7b1aecd172e93f6f7f75aae92186.svg.br    1.43 KiB           [emitted]
                media/images/logo-a53b7b1aecd172e93f6f7f75aae92186.svg.gz    1.67 KiB           [emitted]
               media/images/logo_red-04d88826aba647ad737f64c8fd5f42ec.png    4.13 KiB           [emitted]
             media/images/three-dots-7627bc820cce40098e897ca98413d895.svg    1.47 KiB           [emitted]
          media/images/three-dots-7627bc820cce40098e897ca98413d895.svg.br   307 bytes           [emitted]
          media/images/three-dots-7627bc820cce40098e897ca98413d895.svg.gz   377 bytes           [emitted]
Entrypoint application [big] = css/application-ad4e93e8.css js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map
Entrypoint images = js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js js/images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.map
Entrypoint stylesheets = css/stylesheets-ad4e93e8.css js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js js/stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.map
 [26] ./app/webpacker/images/logo_red.png 104 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [27] ./app/webpacker/images/icon/contact-icon.png 113 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [28] ./app/webpacker/images/icon/credit-card.png 112 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [44] ./app/webpacker/packs/stylesheets.scss 39 bytes {0} {2} [built]
 [45] ./app/webpacker/packs/images.js + 1 modules 141 bytes {0} {1} [built]
      | ./app/webpacker/packs/images.js 18 bytes [built]
      | ./app/webpacker/images/index.js 108 bytes [built]
 [83] ./app/webpacker/packs/application.js 1.33 KiB {0} [built]
[127] ./app/webpacker/src/javascripts/general.js 86 bytes {0} [built]
[128] ./app/webpacker/src/javascripts/cocoon.js 3.97 KiB {0} [built]
[129] ./app/webpacker/images sync \.(gif|jpg|png|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/ 361 bytes {0} [built]
[130] ./app/webpacker/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold.otf 116 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[131] ./app/webpacker/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold.ttf 116 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[132] ./app/webpacker/images/fonts/Noah-Regular.otf 114 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[133] ./app/webpacker/images/logo.svg 100 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[134] ./app/webpacker/images/three-dots.svg 106 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[135] ../node_modules/@rails/actiontext/app/javascript/actiontext/index.js + 1 modules 2.64 KiB {0} [built]
      |    2 modules
    + 122 hidden modules

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  media/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-912ec66d.svg (434 KiB)
  js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js (569 KiB)
  js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map.gz (491 KiB)
  js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map.br (402 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  application (764 KiB)
      css/application-ad4e93e8.css
      js/application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--7-2!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??re
f--7-3!app/webpacker/packs/stylesheets.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-2!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-3!./app/webpacker/packs/st
ylesheets.scss 829 KiB {0} [built]
    [3] ./app/webpacker/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold.otf 116 bytes {0} [built]
    [4] ./app/webpacker/images/fonts/Noah-ExtraBold.ttf 116 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] ./app/webpacker/images/fonts/Noah-Regular.otf 114 bytes {0} [built]
        + 8 hidden modules
Done in 17.52s.

/opt/app/public/packs/manifest.json
/opt/app/public/packs/manifest.json.br
/opt/app/public/packs/manifest.json.gz

/opt/app/public/packs/css:
application-ad4e93e8.css
application-ad4e93e8.css.br
application-ad4e93e8.css.gz
stylesheets-ad4e93e8.css
stylesheets-ad4e93e8.css.br
stylesheets-ad4e93e8.css.gz

/opt/app/public/packs/js:
application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js
application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.LICENSE.txt
application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.br
application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.gz
application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map
application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map.br
application-71c9136107a4a504df9b.js.map.gz
images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js
images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.br
images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.gz
images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.map
images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.map.br
images-aef2116965a80a23e5d5.js.map.gz
stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js
stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.br
stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.gz
stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.map
stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.map.br
stylesheets-3d6d364a819b59783614.js.map.gz

/opt/app/public/packs/media:
fonts
images
6.4M    /opt/app/public/packs
Removing intermediate container 5c31033bd34c
 ---> 45c4a0be56fe
Step 35/35 : RUN ls /opt/app/public/packs/
 ---> Running in 5ade2c36f7c4
ls: cannot access '/opt/app/public/packs/': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ls /opt/app/public/packs/' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

And here's the whole Dockerfile:

```
# Allow the image to be built with any Ruby version.
# This arg is only available at build time and only usable by the `FROM` lines.
ARG ruby_version=2.7

################################################################################
# Base image with dependencies to support development and production images.
#
FROM ruby:${ruby_version}-slim AS base

# git-core:         fetching gems stored in git repos
# build-essential   building native gems (gcc, make, etc)
# libpq-dev         PostgreSQL development headers for building `pg` gem
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      git-core \
      build-essential \
      libpq-dev \
      curl

# Install node and yarn for dealing with webpack assets
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install --global yarn && \
    echo '--modules-folder /opt/node_modules' >> ~/.yarnrc

# Update RubyGems system software
RUN gem update --system --silent

# Create a directory for custom binaries and executable scripts
RUN mkdir /opt/bin
ENV PATH=/opt/bin:$PATH

# Add helper script that will ensure the correct version of Bundler is installed
COPY docker/install-bundler.sh /opt/bin/install-bundler

# Add entrypoint used during development that ensures gems are up to date
COPY docker/entrypoint.dev.sh /opt/bin/entrypoint-dev

# Home of the application source code.
WORKDIR /opt/app
VOLUME /opt/app

# Specify the target application environment of this build
# It should be one of:
# development, test, production
ARG app_env

ENV APP_ENV=$app_env \
    NODE_ENV=$app_env \
    RAILS_ENV=$app_env \
    RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true


################################################################################
# Stage that includes bundler, the gems, and source code
#
# Used by the test runner in CI and for building standlone runnable images
# that will work for any environment. Not used by docker-compose.
FROM base AS app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /opt/app/

RUN install-bundler

# Use helper script that runs 'bundle install' appropriately given the APP_ENV
COPY docker/bundle-install-env.sh /opt/bin/bundle-install-env
RUN bundle-install-env

# Copy specific files and directories we need to run the app
COPY .rubocop.yml config.ru Rakefile ./
COPY app/ ./app/
COPY bin/ ./bin/
COPY config/ ./config/
COPY db/ ./db/
COPY lib/ ./lib/
COPY public/ ./public/
COPY test/ ./test/
COPY vendor/ ./vendor/

# Pre-compile and cache code using bootsnap
RUN bin/bootsnap precompile --gemfile app/ lib/


################################################################################
# Builder stage for release image prep
#
FROM app AS builder

# Remove cached .gem files and gem component we don't need (e.g. tests, docs)
# This is to save space in the final image.
RUN rm /usr/local/bundle/cache/*.gem && \
    rm -rf /usr/local/bundle/gems/*/{benchmarks,doc,example,perf,spec,test,tests}/

COPY babel.config.js package.json postcss.config.js yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

# Rails refuses to run the precompile without a secret_key_base
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

RUN bin/rails assets:precompile && \
    test -d /opt/app/public/packs && \
    ls /opt/app/public/packs/* && \
    du -sh /opt/app/public/packs

RUN ls /opt/app/public/packs/

# ... omitted the final distribution stage based on a fresh image; it never gets that far
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `VOLUME` line.

The only particularly obvious effect of a `VOLUME` directive is that it prevents any following `RUN` command from changing that directory.  Declaring a `VOLUME` in your Dockerfile is almost never necessary (and volumes aren't appropriate storage for source code); you can just delete that line and nothing bad will happen.

Comment: I'm somewhat astonished that I haven't run into this issue before. I was under the false impression that `VOLUME` was like `EXPOSE`: only there to annotate/document your file. The mount is used during development.

Removing that fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: `VOLUME` prevents `RUN` commands from having effects; it causes `docker run` to create an anonymous volume (and leak storage); and I believe it will cause Compose to persist that specific directory across container runs (and ignore changes in the image).